# Fastest Pitch Recorded

Tags: probability

I stumbled across a question that was:

> What will be the fastest pitch recorded in the 1st inning of the
>   baseball game?

The answers were either $Speed\le94.99$ or $Speed\ge95$ measured in MPH.

I want to know the process of how to solve this question. There is no information in terms of raw numbers, but I have made some assumptions to make the question easier.

**Assumptions**

1. Assume pitchers speed on pitches is $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for the first inning.
2. Assume the pitcher pitched 14 pitches per inning, for a total of 126 pitches.
3. Assume 1 pitcher for the 1 inning.

**My Simple Answer**

Look at is as a binomial probability to find the Probability of at least one pitch greater than 95 in the 1st inning.

This can be solved as $$1- {14 \choose 0}p(S)^0(1-p(S))^{14}$$ Such that 
$$p(S) =\int_{95}^{\inf}\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{(2\pi)}}*e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dx$$ with $x=95$. From here, plug and chug.

My only gripe is that the average and standard deviation is based on pitches in the first inning. This level of information is not readily available. How could one attempt it with only average and standard deviation of all pitches available? Or is that wicked complicated?

**More complicated**

Then I thought, what about if we condition on the type of pitch, thus Assume Fast-Ball Pitch and Off-Speed Pitch as $\mu_{FB}=\mu_1$ with $\sigma_1$ and $\mu_{OFF}=\mu_2$ with $\sigma_2$. The Fast-Ball gets used $d$% of the time and Off-Speed as $(1-d$%$)=g$% of the time. How would this change the answer?

I think instead of $P(S)$, we would have $P(FB)*P(UsageFB)+P(OFF)*P(UsageOFF)$, then plug and chug the respective averages and standard deviations.

Answer (score 0):

Most baseball games are below the professional level and have a pitcher who is not capable of anything like $95$ mph.  Without real data there is no point in all the mathematical formulas.  You do not have to multiply by $9$ for innings as the question only asks about the first inning.

Comment: $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are real numbers though. The answer of most baseball games are below the professional level with a pitcher not capable of anything like 95mph does not solve the question because the question still works for any pitcher in any league.